# How loud is the Perseus cluster?

Tags: waves, pressure, acoustics, astronomy, galaxy-clusters

The gas near the center of the Perseus cluster exhibits quasiperiodic pressure oscillations that can be [interpreted as sound](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/chandra/news/new-nasa-black-hole-sonifications-with-a-remix.html). I found a [paper](https://academic.oup.com/mnras/article/344/3/L43/1015198) that says that these pressure waves have a wavelength of about 11 kiloparsecs, a speed of 1170 km/s, and period of 9.6 million years. (My math says that 11 kps / (1170 km/s) equals 9.2 million years, not 9.6 million - but whatever, close enough.) This corresponds to an infrasonic (to say the least) frequency of about $3 \times 10^{-15}$ Hz.

But what's the amplitude of these pressure waves? The paper only seems to discuss relative amplitudes at different locations within the cluster, not absolute amplitudes.